# Need some tutorial for writing automation tests in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, automation, watin

Can any one please help me in providing a sample tests for writing automation tests using visual studio. A little bit confused at how to set up if already have tests written in watin. Just to give me a start.

Comment: You've tagged this with "selenium" but essentially you are running VS Team web tests?

Comment: Cause I am also looking for possibilities of using selenium instead of Watin.

Comment: then you should ask a separate, selenium question. One question per question, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Visual Studio Click menu Test > New ...
And here are next steps: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/01/20/coded-ui-test.aspx

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the link. It really helps. My current scenario is Watin, nunit, vb.net, teamcity for running automated tests on integration server. What can be the alternative of this scenario if using VS2010 test and also running the tests instead of nunit. What is best approach.

Comment: This answer is assuming you have the correct version of visual studio, to get the coded ui test option.